# Formula to split price equally among the people

Tags: java, algorithm, math, payment

It's about 3 days that I'm trying to figure out a generic formula to split payment among people. So far, in java, I do something like this:

```
NameArray [Me, Dad, Mum, Sister]

singlePayment[10,5,15,20,2,4]

totalPaymentperPerson[25, 20, 6, 15]
```

Then, I order by highest price the `totalPaymentperPerson --> [25,20,15,6]`

So the nameArray became `[Me, Dad, Sister, Mum]`

(All the price and the name are added dynamically by the user)

So now, the total cost is: `66`

The price per person is: `16.5 --> 66/4`

```
debtorArray [Sister, mum] --> the pay 15 and 6, under the cost per person of 16.5

receiverArray[Me, Dad] --> [20.5, 3,5]

differenceArray[1.5, 10.5] ---> cpp - debtorArray
```

Now I have to make something like that:

- Mum owes Me 8.5
- Mum owes Dad 6.5
- Sister owes Dad 1.5

I can't figure out how to achieve this..If I do a formula for 3 participants, then if I have 6 participants, the formula doesn't work anymore..or maybe it work if I have 3 payments, but not with 5..Is there any way to do that with logic? I have too much "if-else" in my code...

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: yes, it's a little bit muddler, but I try..

Comment: Thanks, could you also try to not format your question text as code?

Comment: yes, for sure! I update the question right now

Comment: This sounds way too complicated. Take a step back: everybody below average payment has to pay the difference and everybody above average has to receive the difference. It does not matter at all who pays to whom. In other words, you can choose at random.

Comment: @Henry yes, but I want to display in a list view something like the bulleted list..so for example, Mum owes Me 8.5. Take a look at the "tricount" app if you want..I'm trying to do something similar to that

Comment: In addition to the comment written by @Henry, you should start doing this in object oriented programming. Write a class `Person` that holds values like payment and procentage share and what else is needed. You can then hold them all in a `List<Person>` or even a `Map<Person, Double>` and perform calculations with those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Considering below **input** data/similar[Note: I have changed your input little bit]:

```
Me = 25
Dad = 20
Mum = 6
Sister = 15
```

Below is the java code to evenly distribute the amount among themselves:

```
package com.shree.algo;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class EvenDistribution {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Double> initialPayment = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Double> computations;


    public EvenDistribution(Map<String,Double> initialPayment){
        this.initialPayment.putAll(initialPayment);
        computations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        subtract();
    }


    private double getAmoutToDistribute(){

        double totalAmount = 0;

        for(double credit: initialPayment.values()){
            totalAmount = totalAmount + credit;
        }

        double amountToDistribute = (totalAmount/initialPayment.size()); 

        return amountToDistribute;
    }

    public void subtract(){

        double amountToDistribute = getAmoutToDistribute();

        for(String name: initialPayment.keySet()){
            double remainingAmount =  initialPayment.get(name) - amountToDistribute ;
            computations.put(name, remainingAmount);
        }
    }

    public void calculate(){

        for(String name: computations.keySet()){
            Double p1amount = computations.get(name);

            if(p1amount>0){
                for(String tmpName: computations.keySet()){
                    double p2amount = computations.get(tmpName);

                    if(!tmpName.equals(name) && p2amount<0){
                            double result = p1amount + p2amount;
                            computations.put(name, 0D);
                            computations.put(tmpName, result);

                            System.out.println(name + "=>" + p1amount + "=>" + tmpName);

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        for(String name: computations.keySet()){
            if(computations.get(name)!=0){
                calculate();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**The Main class:**

```
package com.shree.algo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Double> initialPayment = new HashMap<>();

        initialPayment.put("Me", 25D);
        initialPayment.put("Dad", 20D);
        initialPayment.put("Mum", 6D);
        initialPayment.put("Sister", 15D);

        EvenDistribution evenDistribution= new EvenDistribution(initialPayment);

        evenDistribution.calculate();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Dad=>3.5=>Mum
Me=>8.5=>Mum
Mum=>1.5=>Sister
```